# For which small $n$ is unknown whether the Mordell-curve has an integral point?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

Since it is not easy to determine the integral points of a Mordell curve $$y^2=x^3+n$$ with integer $n\ne 0$, I came to the following questions :

> $1)$ What is the smallest (in absolute value) integer $n$ , such that it is unknown whether the Mordell-curve $y^2=y^3+n$ has an integral point ?
>
> $2)$ What is the smallest (in absolute value) integer $n$, such that the complete list of the integral points is not known ?

Since I found a list for $-10^7\le n\le 10^7$, the absolute value should be greater than $10^7$.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Bennet has mentioned the example on MSE, due to Noam Elkies with
$$n = 509142596247656696242225,$$ where there are at least $125$ pairs of integral solutions, but where not all integral solutions are known. But of course this may not be the smallest $n$. Noam Elkies has more information concerning the Mordell equation $x^3 – y^2 = k$ on his homepage, e.g., [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/hall.html), concerning Hall's conjecture, but you will certainly know this already (as well as Cremona's database etc.).