# Can we check efficiently whether a given integer solution of a Mordell-curve is the smallest?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, mordell-curves

Suppose, we know an integer solution $(y,x)$ of a Mordell-curve $$y^2=x^3+k$$

For example $$25124268633183975113^2=8578189162349^3-251669431780$$

So for $$k=-251 669 431 780$$ , the pair $$(25 124 268 633 183 975 113, 8 578 189 162 349)$$

is a solution.

> Can we check efficiently (without brute force) whether there is an integer  solution with a smaller $x$ for the given $k$ ? In other words, can we check efficiently whether the solution is the smallest ?

Comment: This is related to your [former question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177287/how-large-can-the-smallest-integral-solution-of-a-mordell-curve-be). In the end, I suppose, there remains a brute force part.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, the question is closely related, but I hoped that at least this problem could be solved efficiently. I heard that most techniques used by compter programs rely on conjectures. Would this considerably accelerate the verification ?